# Sequence of multiples of two matrices over $F_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Let $A,B\in M_{n}\mathbb(F_2)$ such that each column has exactly one entry equal to 1 and all the other entries are zero.
Can you find a criterion/algorithm to check if there is a sequence of multiples of $A,B$ (like $ABBABAA,BABBA,...$) so that the product equal to $P\in M_{n}\mathbb(F_2)$ - each column of P is $e_i$ for constant $i$?

for example - if both matrices are invertible there is no such sequence so that the product is $P$.

**A little Progress**:

Let's look at the graph whose the adjacency matrix of the graph is $A$.
If:

1) The graph is connected

2) There is exist a single loop

3) there are no cycles

there's exist a positive integer k such that $A^k = P$

Comment: $P$ is invertible. If $A=B=P$, this satisfies your initial criteria and trivially any sequence you want to use gives a product equal to $P$. So, I am a bit confused by your "for example".

Also, what do you mean that $P$ is $e_i$ for the same i? Do you mean that $P$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: $P$ isn't  invertible. $P_(i,j) = 1$ for all $j$ otherwise $P_(m,k) = 0$ where $m$ doesn't equal to $i$.

Comment: If $P$ is the set of elementary columns, it is most definitely invertible. Its inverse is itself. If it is not the identity matrix, then please describe what you mean by $P$ because I am not understanding your notation.

Comment: Each column of $P$ is $e_i$ for some constant $i$ - which means there is a row of ones and all the other entries are zero.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: How can a (directed) graph be connected and yet have no cycles?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm that runs in $O(n^2)$ time:

First, observe that $A$ and $B$ map every elementary column to another elementary column, so what we really have is a finite set $X=\{\mathbf e_1,\ldots\mathbf e_n\}$ and two functions $f_A, f_B:X\to X$, and we want to know if there is some composition sequence of $f_A$ and $f_B$ that is a constant function.

The crucial fact is now:

> There is a composition sequence that maps all of $X$ to a single element **if and only if** for every *pair* of elements of $X$ there exists a composition sequence that maps both elements to the same element.

Here "only if" is trivial. For "if", suppose we have a certain subset $A\subseteq X$ that we want to compress into a single element. Choose two elements of the subset, and apply the composition sequence that unifies them. The result is of that, $A'=(f_1\circ \cdots\circ f_k)(A)$, has fewer elements than $A$; proceed by induction until $|A|=1$.

Now construct a directed graph whose nodes are the size-2 subsets of $X$, plus a designated "you win" node. The node $\{x_1,x_2\}$ has edges going to $\{f_A(x_1),f_A(x_2)\}$ and $\{f_B(x_1),f_B(x_2)\}$, or to "you win" if either of these is a singleton set.

Now the desired property holds if every node in the graph can reach "you win". This can be checked by a single depth-first through the *opposite* graph in time linear in the size of the graph -- which means quadratic in $n$.